# OpenLayers formatting MousePosition (change x with y) React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, openlayers

Using OpenLayers in React I'm currently displaying the coordinates when you mouse over the map. However, they are in the "wrong" format, I want them to be North, East, but they are now East, North.

Do anyone know how to switch the order of these?
The following code is where I apply the mouse over to the map:

```
new MousePosition({
      coordinateFormat: Coordinate.createStringXY(0),
      projection: 'EPSG:25833'
    })
```

(Please note that I have found a similar question, but it seems outdated, and I could not get their solution to work.)

Comment: Show more code about how you display them.

Comment: this is all the code for showing the mouseposition, I'm using functionality from openlayers

Comment: If you need YX format you will need a custom function such as
`coordinateFormat: function(coordinate) { return Coordinate.format(coordinate, '{y}, {x}', 0) },`

Comment: Thank you @Mike worked like a charm!